# apache/php error logs Daily logs rotation in WAMP 64bit (Windows)

Tags: php, apache, logging, wamp

the apache_logs and php_error logs has been created by the wamp application.
I m looking for a way to rotate the logs by days/hours or limit the log file size without external installation or third party software.

I did not find d a solution like that, is it possible?  the log file getting large to 1-2gb  and I don't want to delete them at all. 
thanks

window 7 , 64 bit , wamp 3

Comment: Google should be your friend [Apache has something that will do this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/rotatelogs.html) you dont need anything external

Comment: But if your `php error log` is getting that big, **I think you have other more pressing issues to solve.**